# SweetAlert2 confirm dialog not working properly in onclick

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, form-submit, sweetalert2

How to fix the `sweetalert2` confirm dialog not working properly in `onclick` event button?

I have a modal popup, for CRUD operations before submitting sweetalert2 confirm dialog is triggered.

Here is my modal form code:

```
<form id="EditForm" asp-action="Edit">
<div class="modal-body">
    
    /*input codes here*/
</div>
<div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-flat" onclick="return submitResult()"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Save Changes</button>
</div>
```

And here is js code:

```
function submitResult() {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                Swal.fire(
                    'Deleted!',
                    'Your file has been deleted.',
                    'success'
                )
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        })
    }
```

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxxJu.gif)

[Apply edit, it still does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV9n8.gif)

Comment: Your code is fine. Looks like the page is refreshing because the button click is being treated as a form submission. You'll need to delay form submission until SWAL is complete or disconnect the button from the form.

Comment: I think, HymmZyy is right.
Just add this code to your submit.

e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-flat" onclick="submitResult(event)"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Save Changes</button>

....

function submitResult(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            Swal.fire(
                'Deleted!',
                'Your file has been deleted.',
                'success'
            )
            document.getElementById("EditForm").submit();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Already tried but nothing happens, it won't submit maybe because my form is from partial view?

Comment: @CoffeeCode please check the form id and try to run the last line only to see if the form is getting submitted. Also put in an alert before the second Swal.fire and see if it's firing properly

Comment: @CoffeeCode also check the value of `result.isConfirmed`

Comment: thank you sir, the problem is that result.isConfirmed not valid, instead result.value,

Comment: Glad to know. Please upvote if it helped and mark it as an answer if it solved your question.