# Using sweet alert for confirmation of deletion record

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

How do I transfer form this correct into using sweet alert.

I use this function site wide and would be nice to use sweetalert2 instead of the generic javascript alert.

https://sweetalert2.github.io/

```
jQueryAjaxDelete = form => {     
 if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?')) {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.action,
            data: new FormData(form),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (res) {
                $('#view-all').html(res.html);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex)
    }
}

  //prevent default form submit event
  return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SweetAlert2 confirm dialog not working properly in onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870284/sweetalert2-confirm-dialog-not-working-properly-in-onclick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new confirm prompt with Sweetalert and remove the vanilla js confirm prompt in your if condition. If confirm is true, then make the delete ajax call.

See code below

```js
jQueryAjaxDelete = form => {
  // Modify as you wish
  const sweetOptions = {
    title: "Delete",
    text: "Are you sure  you want to delete this record?",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
    cancelButtonText: "Cancel!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false 
  }
  
  swal(sweetOptions, (isConfirmed) => {
    if (isConfirmed) {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: form.action,
          data: new FormData(form),
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function (res) {
              $('#view-all').html(res.html);
              
              // Fire a delete alert with SweetAlert here
              swal("Deleted!", "Deleted!", "success");
          },
          error: function (err) {
              console.log(err)
              swal("Cancelled", "Delete failed", "error");
          }
      })
    } else {
        swal("Cancelled", "Delete cancelled", "error");
    }
  }
   //prevent default form submit event
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you my javascript is not the best this worked grand Swal is really nice hate seeing the old prompts this day and age.

Comment: Makes sense,  I'm not sure why they had to downvote your question, it was very valid.  I did a little refactoring, you don't need `try/catch` block because the ajax call `success` and `error` methods handle that for you.